# calculate difference between two hours

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to calculate the difference between two hours.
I implement this code:

```
 changEndHour($event: any, i: number) {
    var arrayControl = this.generalForm.get('hours') as FormArray;
    let startHour = arrayControl.at(i).get('startHour').value,
    startMin = arrayControl.at(i).get('startMin').value,
    endMin = arrayControl.at(i).get('endMin').value,
      endHour = $event.split(":"), date1 = new Date(), date2 = new Date();


      date1.setHours(startHour, startMin).toString();
      let d1=date1.setHours(startHour, startMin).toString();
      date2.setHours(endHour, endMin).toString();
      let d2=date2.setHours(endHour, endMin).toString();
      let hours = (Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60).toFixed(2);
      arrayControl.at(i).get('result').setValue(hours);
    }
```

When I tested, this code does not calculate the result correctly.
I'm trying to calculate 13:00 - 12:10. the result is 0.83 which is wrong.
How can I improve my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly well. The result is the percentage of 60 minutes. So, by performing the following calculation

```
60 * 0.83 = 49.8
```

You can get the desired result in minutes.

The solution for your problem would be

```
let result = str.split(".")
console.log("Time difference is " + str[0] + " h, " + (60 * str[1]) + " min")
```

Comment: I want to display the result of hours that's why I used(difference/1000 / 60 / 60)

Comment: What do you want to display exactly? Can you give me an example?

Comment: 13:00 - 12:30 => 0 h , 30 min

Comment: I edited my comment with the solution that you need.